# Mapped strings in Python? How can I paste a string just pressing a button of the keyboard?

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

How can I link a string to a specific button of the kwyboard in order to paste this string every time the user presses it? Where the string is pasted depends by where the cursor is in use, it could be Word, a notepad, the browser, and so on. Is it possible to write it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the string might need to be pasted in a browser, or wherever the cursor is, I decided to use the modules pynput and keyboard. I've found that keyboard often works in web browsers, and other platforms. This is something that I came up with using pynput and keyboard:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import keyboard

def check(key):
    if key == Key.enter: #I used the key enter but it can be whatever
        keyboard.write('Whatever your string is')


with Listener(on_press = check) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

For more information, I recommend checking out the documentation in keyboard and pynput.